# Set of limit points of Riemann Integrable functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I've looked around for answers to this question. It seems like perhaps I don't have enough knowledge of functional analysis to figure out the answer (or even understand the answer), but I'm intrigued.

Consider the set of Riemann Integrable functions over a closed real interval [a,b]. I know that there exists a sequence of Riemann Integrable functions who's limit is **not** Riemann Integrable. However his begs the question, what is the set of limit points of Riemann Integrable functions?

The question arises from my essay on Daniell Integrals. First we define a **lattice of real valued functions** L such that

\begin{equation*}
(f \lor g)  := \max(f,g) 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(f \land g) := \min(f,g)
\end{equation*}

We then define the **completion** of a lattice $L$, denoted by by $L^{*}$, is defined to be the intersection of all sets $L'$ of real valued functions such that

\begin{equation*} L \subset L'
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
f_{n} \in L', f_{n}\uparrow f \implies f \in L'
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
g_{n} \in L', g_{n}\downarrow g \implies g \in L'
\end{equation*}

So essentially it is a larger lattice (I have proven it is a lattice) such that we have closure under monotone limits.

Comment: Limit as in *pointwise* limit?

Comment: Yes, pointwise limit.